# Visualizar dato seleccionado en select de vista edit.blade

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

En la vista edit.blade no logro que se visualice el dato seleccionado previamente en la vista create.blade.

¿Como debo hacer para ver la opción seleccionada en la vista edit.blade?

Aqui dejo el codigo de la vista Create del select:

```
<div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-xs-12">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label>Tipo de Incidencia</label>
                <select name="Tipo_incidencia" id="Tipo_incidencia" class="form-control">
                      <option value="" selected>Seleccionar</option>
                      <option value="Primer Ingreso">Primer Ingreso</option>
                      <option value="Ing. Receta Mensual">Ing. Receta Mensual</option>
                      <option value="Ing. Receta Complementaria">Ing. Receta Complementaria</option>
                      <option value="Ing. Seguimiento">Ing. Seguimiento</option>
                      <option value="Ing. Co-Pago">Ing. Co-Pago</option>
                      <option value="Ing. Partida Defuncion">Ing. Partida Defunción</option>
                      <option value="Suspension de Tratamiento">Suspensión de Tratamiento</option>
                      <option value="Sentencia Revocada">Sentencia Revocada</option>
                </select>
             </div>
        </div>
```

En la vista edit.blade para el select en cuestión tengo el mismo código que el de la vista create, ya que no se como hacer para solucionarlo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primero que todo el controlador debe enviarte datos a la vista para que puedas poblar los datos como se muestra en el siguiente ejemplo:

```
    public function edit($id)
    {
        $curso = Cursos::find($id);
        return view('form-edit')->with(compact('curso'));
    }
```

Ahora si esta parte esta funcionando correctamente y lo que deseas es construir el `select` con **Laravel**, usa este ejemplo para aplicarlo a tu código:

suponiendo que usamos **curso** y la variable es **incidencia**.

El código a usar en **blade** seria el siguiente:

```
{{-- construccion arreglo con items para select  --}}
@php
    // listado 
    $array  = ["Primer Ingreso",
                "Ing. Receta Mensual",
                "Ing. Receta Complementaria",
                "Ing. Seguimiento",
                "Ing. Co-Pago",
                "Ing. Partida Defuncion",
                "Suspension de Tratamiento",
                "Sentencia Revocada"];
@endphp


<div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-xs-12">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label>Tipo de Incidencia</label>
            <select name="Tipo_incidencia" id="Tipo_incidencia" class="form-control">
                  {{-- construccion de las opciones con blade --}}
                  @foreach($array as $item)
                      <option value="{{ $item }}" @if($curso->incidencia=== $item) selected='selected' @endif>{{ $item }}</option>
                  @endforeach
            </select>
         </div>
</div>
```

Lo que se esta haciendo es lo siguiente:

1) Con el helper `@foreach($array as $item)` se hace un recorrido de cada `item` que tiene el `@array`.

2) se va construyendo el option y aqui se coloca el valor del item correspondiente para `value="{{ $item }}`

3) Aquí se hace una comparación con el valor actual del item contra el atributo ya registrado en la tabla de `$curso->incidencia`. 
 `@if($curso->incidencia=== $item) selected='selected' @endif` de ser cierto entonces se coloca `selected`

4) finalmente se pone el nombre de la opcion de la misma forma que se uso con el `value=""` que es: `{{ $item }}`

Espero que sea de tu ayuda...

Comment: Muchísimas gracias, excelente respuesta y explicada, gracias mil.